# почему не убивается процесс

Tags: pyqt

есть следующий код

```
def loadEngine(self):
    filename=QtGui.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, "Open File","","*.exe")
    #if self.process.state()==QtCore.QProcess.Running:
    self.process.kill()
    self.process.start(str(filename))
```

проблема в следующем: если self.process уже запущен и я хочу запустить другой процесс, выбрав соответствующий файл, то новый процесс не запускается. Как я понял, это происходит из-за того, что старый процесс не убивается. Вопрос: почему он не убивается? Помогите пожалуйста.

Answer (score -1):

всего то нужно добавить `self.process.waitForFinished()` после `self.process.kill()`

Comment: Не является ответом на вопрос. Чтобы оставить свои замечания или попросить у автора внести уточнения, оставьте комментарий к соответствующему сообщению. - [Из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/108648)

Comment: @rjhdby, он как бы на свой вопрос и дал ответ :D